# New tab in IWD storelocator

Tags: magento-1.9

Hi I am working in my magento project. I've installed IWD store Locator recently. I can see this from admin side like this.

[image]

Now I want to create another tab associated with this Store Locator.Where should i modify my code? How can i override it with a folder which is in local pool.

What I want is like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have to modify module's system.xml for change configuration. Here you can add new group for your tab data.

Answer (score 0):

System configurations are managed from module's `system.xml`, which is located at file:

```
app/code/<code_pool>/<package_name>/<module_name>/etc/system.xml
```

You can open this file and add a new group for new tab.

**Note**:

- `<code_pool>`: local or community or core
- `<package_name>`: IWD in your case
- `<module_name>`: Storelocator or StoreLocator in your case

Please let me know if you find any problem.

Comment: Okay. I copied my IWD folder from community to local. and made some changes there. but nothing reflecting on the screen

Comment: There is no need to change location from community to local folder

Comment: You can make changes in app/code/community/IWD/StoreLocator/etc/system.xml file directly.